# How to test subject with dependency?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, tdd

I want to develop a card-base game in Ruby, and I want to do it in **TDD** way.

The first class I want to write is **Player**.
Each player has a **hand** with 13 cards and on his/her turn can choose and play 1 card to pass.

I have not developed any other classes (like card, hand, ..), I want to know how I can test this subject which has dependency to other classes?

I know about Mocks but I don't know how can I use them.

For example in this scenario we know that when a player **plays** one card that card should have to be removed from his/her hand.

This is my code :

```
require "rspec"
require "lib/player"

describe Player do
  before(:each) do
    hand=mock("Hand")
    hand.should_receive(:count).and_return(13)
    subject.hand=hand
  end

  it "should choose and play a card from her/his hand" do
      subject.hand.count.should==13
      card_selected=subject.play(2)      # card #2 in his/her hand
      subject.hand.count.should=12
   end
end
```

Also, in the implementation we are dependent to the Hand class, how can I handle it ?

Comment: Perhaps you are getting ahead of yourself. You shouldn't have to mock Hand simply because it doesn't exist yet. That's going to cause you to rewrite the test after you create the Hand class. The test shouldn't have to change. Hold off on testing the play method until you have a basic Hand class with which to test it.

Comment: I disagree.  Writing tests before you have the supporting class will help you to write much more meaningful API's, since you are basically writing tests for the API that you wish you had.  You then go implement that API to make the tests pass.

Comment: I think Marc Talbot is right , one of the usage of Mocks is to test subject without the knowledge of its dependencies.

Comment: After you add the Hand class will you leave the mocks? What happens if you change the behavior of the count method? Then you've got tests that should fail but pass because you're not hitting the actual class method.

Comment: Tom , I don't know , thats the reason I'm asking. I've developed the code with the way that you suggested , but still eager to learn the best approach

Comment: @Tom, you're right, mocking the Hand here might obfuscate changes made to the real Hand class later, that's one thing to keep in mind, but that shouldn't stop you using this approach. The resulting interface you come up with for Hand will be much cleaner because you'll know how it will be used rather than relying on (small/big)-design-up-front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen my share of mocking and stubbing, and I've seen huge test suites pass even though the app was broken beyond belief because half the code didn't even exist anymore.

I've come to the conclusion that stubbing and mocking should be used with extreme care. That, and the fact that it should be introduced as late as possible.

**This is one of the cases where it's too early to mock.** You're mocking just because you don't have the class `Hand` yet.

As a sidenote, the test itself needs improvement. Take a closer look at these lines:

```
hand.should_receive(:count).and_return(13)
subject.hand=hand
subject.hand.count.should==13
subject.hand.count.should=12
```

Of course, `subject.hand.count.should==13` passes, you just stubbed it to this value. And of course, `subject.hand.count.should=12` passes because you didn't call `==`. If you changed it to a real expectation, you'd be wondering why it fails. It fails because you stubbed `Hand#count` to *always* return 13.

What you're actually doing here is mocking part of the API under test. Don't do this. Instead, **start with baby steps**. This could mean:

- You start on the inside and work your way out. So start with the innermost class, `Hand` in this case. Once you get to `Player`, all the pieces will fit together just fine without mocking.
- You start with `Player` **until you absolutely need the other class** (do that if the argument of a "meaningful API" appeals to you). This means: Wait for a `NameError` on `Hand`. Then implement just as much of the `Hand` class as necessary. Then get back to `Player`

Also, looking at your code raises the question: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to separate a player and her hand in the first place?